# IntelliTrace with VSTO?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, ms-word, vsto, intellitrace

I have a VSTO Word add-in that is built with Visual Studio 2010, in C# targeting the .NET 4.0 framework.

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2010.

I also have a bug that no one in QA for the life of them can figure out how to reproduce -- it just happens sometimes -- we're pretty sure it's our code that's causing it -- but yeah, that's that.

What do I have to do, to make IntelliTrace run on a machine without VisualStudio and attach it to my add-in which is loaded by Word at run time and have it produce .ITRACE files that I can open with Visual Studio 2010 so that I can step through the code and see what's going on?

Comment: There is a standalone IntelliTrace collector for Visual Studio 2012 or newer, but unfortunately it isn't available for Visual Studio 2010.
It would quite a bit of work to take a non-standalone version of IntelliTrace and get it to work on a machine without Visual Studio.

Comment: Can the standalone 2012 IntelliTrace collector generate files that can be used with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Unfortunately the VS2012 version of IntelliTrace has a pretty different file format so newer files cannot be opened by VS2010. We do support the opposite case, opening VS2010 in VS2012, but not the forward-compat case.